# Connecting from a Delphi app to an Interbase server on the same machine

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8, interbase

I have an XE8 project that (is supposed to) access an Interbase server running on the same machine.  A few days ago it was working fine, but has developed the problem that if I attempted to set the `Connected` property of a `TIBDatabase` component to `True`, either in the IDE or in code at run-time, I get the error:

`Connection rejected by remote interface`

Attempting to connect to the server using the IBConsole utility also produces this error.

I've cleared as much of Interbase as I can find from the machine & its registry and re-installed it but the problem persists.  Googling the message text finds a modest number of things, but I've tried the few suggested solutions to no useful effect.

Btw, the PortQry utility confirms that port 3050 is open and that the gds_db server is listening.

My question, obviously, is does anyone recognise this symptom and know how to fix it?

Comment: I have seen this. `gds32.dll` in folder `windows\sysWOW64` was older version. Maybe a good idea to look and check this file in entire computer.

Comment: @ValMarinov:  Yes, I was hoping it was something like that, but unfortunately not.  When I cleared IB from the machine, I deleted every instance of Gds32.Dll on it, and after re-installing I now have only the one in the IB install's bin sub-folder and a copy of it in sysWOW64; it's version 12.0.4.357 dated 11 August 2015.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually found the cause of this problem.  I have an instance of the Firebird server installed on the problem machine and set up as a service, and at some point recently, its `Startup Type` had been changed from `Disabled` to `Automatic` and the fact that it was running was evidently causing the IB server to misbehave.  Reverting it to `Disabled' caused the problem to vanish.

I imagine that it was actually the FB server that was the 'remote interface' that was rejecting the connection.